# What's the maximum name length for an Azure Logic App (Standard and Consumption)?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I found disparate answers in many sites and not a clear or definite response in the Microsoft sites.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself in the Azure Portal and got these values (as of today):

- Standard: maximum 43 characters.
- Consumption: maximum 80 characters.

The ".azurewebsites.net" host name part is not taken into account for the length.